# What is the difference in usage between 势必， 必定 and 必然?

Tags: meaning, difference

势必 be bound to; certainly will

必定 to be bound to; to be sure to

必然 inevitable; certain; necessity

Comment: Q for the sake of Q? ＂实用汉语近义虚词词典＂ **必定（副）／必然（副；形）／一定（副；形）［相同］**  都是副词，作状语，加强肯定的语气，强调＂肯定是这样＂。经常可以互换，但意思稍有不同：＂必定、一定＂主要强调说话人根据情况对事物的判断，主观性强；＂必然＂主要是客观规律、道理上来判断，客观性强。＂必定、必然＂多用于书面语，＂一定＂口语和书面语都用：（１）坚持多听多说，听说能力必定会提高。（必然✓一定✓）（２）天天打太极拳必定对身体有好处。（必然✓一定✓）（３）只要你付出努力，必然有收获。（必定，✓一定✓）（４）只要继续努力，你的理想必然会实现。（必定✓，一定✓）（５）如果自己解决不了，她一定会来找你帮忙。（必定✓必然✓）（６）骄傲的人一定会犯错误。（必定✓必然✓）  **［不同］**    １。有判断＂是＂的判断句中用＂必定、一定＂不能用＂必然＂：（１）我看，他必定是在中山大学学习的外国留学生。（一定✓必然✗）（２）从饮食习惯来看，他必定是南方人。（一定✓必然✗）（３）听口音，一定是北京人。（必定✓必然✗）（４）看样子，她一定是个演员。（必定✓必然✗）２。＂必定、一定＂还可以用在第一人称的句子中，表示说话人态度坚决，不过＂一定＂更常用，特别在口语中，很少用＂必定＂；＂一定＂可以和＂要＂连用，可以用在祈使句用，＂必定＂不能：

Comment: （１）你放心，东西我一定按时送到。（必定✓必然✗）（２）明天的会议我一定参加。（必定✓必然✗）（３）他一定要这样做，我们也没有办法（必定✗必然✗）（４）明天你一定要来啊！（必定✗必然✗）３。＂一定＂还可以用在表示推测的问句中，＂必定、必然＂不能：（１）你一定累了吧？快坐下休息休息。（必定✗必然✗）（２）你一定很想知道这件事吧？（必定✗必然✗）（３）他一定是玛丽的男朋友吧？（必定✗必然✗）４。＂必然、必定＂还有形容词的用法，作谓语时可以互换，但多用＂必然＂；作定语时意思不同，不能呼唤：＂必然＂表示＂客观上一定有的＂，＂一定＂表示＂某种程度的、特定的＂。＂必定＂没有形容词的用法：（１）付出了就会有收获，这是必然的。（一定✓必定✗）（２）新事物代替旧事物，这是必然的。（一定✓必定✗）（３）这两件事情不一定有必然联系。（必定✗一定✗）（４）我早就知道，这是必然的结果。（必定✗一定✗）（５）这两件事情之间可能有一定关系。（必然✗必定✗）（６）解决这个问题，他有一定的把握。（必然✗必定✗）

Comment: includes 势必: **必定（副）／一定（副）／势必（副）［相同］**  都是副词，表示非常肯定的判断或推论。＂必定、一定＂比＂势必＂的语气更强，＂必定、势必＂多用于书面语。用在复句中表示根据客观形势推测结果时可以互换：（１）最近连续暴雨，蔬菜价格必定上涨。（势必✓一定✓）（２）通过这项合作，两国人民之间的友谊必定会不断增强。（势必✓一定✓）（３）技术如果不改进，产品质量一定会出现问题。（必定✓，势必✓）（４）双方不肯定让步，一定使矛盾更加激烈。（必定✓，势必✓）（５）长期睡眠不足，发展下去势必损害健康。（必定✓一定✓）（６）如果世界各国联合采取行动，势必有利于解决中东问题。（必定✓一定✓） **［不同］**  １。表示明确的主观判断或推论时，特别是在单句中，用＂必定、一定＂不用＂势必＂：（１）这种新展品必定能占领市场。（一定✓势必✗）（２）你的意见，他必定会同意。（一定✓势必✗）（３）做坏事的人必定没有好下场！（一定✓势必✗）（４）他一定是外国人。（一定✓势必✗）（５）他一定是来这里旅行的。（一定✓势必✗）（６）老张这么做，一定有充分的理由。（一定✓势必✗）２。＂一定＂还可以表示说话人坚决的态度和决心，＂必定，势必＂不能：（１）我一定好好学习，你放心吧！（必定✗势必✗）（２）我们一定要好好打，争取得冠军。（必定✗势必✗）

Comment: （３）他说今天一定去医院检查身体。（必定✗势必✗）（４）他表示一定会认真考虑，尽快做出答复。（必定✗势必✗）
３。＂一定＂可以用在祈使句中，提出要求：＂必定、势必＂不能：（１）演出那天，你一定要来给我捧场啊！（必定✗势必✗）（２）你一定得帮我这个忙！（必定✗势必✗）（３）你可一定不要忘了呀！（必定✗势必✗）

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *势必 be bound to; certainly will*

势必 = 形势必然 (situation will certainly be)

**势必**(compound word):**bound to**

Example: 决赛:德国对巴西, 到時**势必**有一场恶斗
(Final match: Germany vs. Brazil, when the time comes, there will **certainly** be a tough fight)

- *emphasize on:'the situation dictate a certain outcome' (the situation of Germany vs. Brazil ensure a tough fight)*

> *必定 to be bound to; to be sure t*o

必= certain; 定= 肯定 = sure

**必定** (compound word):**certainly**; **surely**

Example: 每次德国遇上巴西, 都**必定**有一场恶斗
(Whenever Germany runs into Brazil,  they would **certainly** have a tough fight)

- *emphasize on 'an absolute certainty' (The fact that 'Germany vs. Brazil is always a tough fight' is an absolute certainty)*

> *必然 inevitable; certain; necessity*

必= certainly; 然= naturally

**必然** (compound word):**certainly**

Example: 如果德国遇上巴西,那**必然**是一场恶斗
(If Germany ran into Brazil, then it would **certainly** be a tough fight)

- *emphasize on 'a natural outcome of certainty' (the nature outcome of Germany vs. Brazil is a tough fight)*